# Can't install telegram-cli with Cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin, telegram

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/blob/master/README-Cygwin.md) on how to install telegram-cli with Cygwin, but when I attempted the step "We need to patch Makefile and loop.c to compile in cygwin. Download this patch then untar. Then, patch in tg directory." and tried to patch using the provided code

```
patch -p1 < telegram-cli-cygwin.patch
```

I got the following message:

```
$ patch -p1 < telegram-cli-cygwin.patch
patching file Makefile
Hunk #1 FAILED at 4.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file Makefile.rej
patching file loop.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 383.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 634.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file loop.c.rej
```

Everything was working fine up until then. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The source does not matches with the version for which the patch was prepared.
Likely it is a following version.

Look on Makefile.rej and loop.c.rej and check the discrepancy.
May be the change were alredy implemented or the context changes do not allow
the patch program to recognize where to implement the changes.